# How do I convert rows into a calendar performance table using Python/Pandas or Excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns which hold dates and performance returns by month back several years. The data is in a csv and looks like this:

```
Date: Return

12/2022: -1%

11/2022: +2%

10/2022: +1%

...

1/2002: -1%
```

I want to convert this into a more traditional performance table/matrix which has a row for each year and a column for each month. So, the end result would look something like this:

```
Year     Jan, Feb, Mar, ..., Dec

2022 -1%, +1%, +2%, ..., -1%

2021 -1%, +1%, +2%, ..., -1%

...

2002 -1%, +1%, +2%, ..., -1%
```

Please advise.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas like so:

```
# simulate csv file // only for copy paste example required
from io import StringIO
csv = StringIO(
"""Date:Return
12/2022:-1%
11/2022:+2%
10/2022:+1%"""
)
```

actual code:

```
# load tabular data, use filepath instead of 'csv' to load from disk
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=':')

# str date to datetime object to access year, month, etc.
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# string to float
df['Return'] = df['Return'].str.strip('%').astype(float) /100

# aggregate data as pivot table
import numpy as np
out = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Return', index=df['Date'].dt.year, columns=df['Date'].dt.month, aggfunc=np.sum)
print(out)
```

Out:

```
Date    10    11    12
Date                  
2022  0.01  0.02 -0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
df[['year','month']] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%b').str.split('-', expand=True)
df = df.pivot(index='year', columns=['month'], values=['return'])
```

output :

```
month    Dec  Jan  Nov  Oct
year                       
2002     NaN  -2%  NaN  NaN
2022     -1%  NaN   1%   0%
```